# Refresh app after the select option language in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, localization

How to refresh app after the select option `language` in Android.
after the select back activity, the layout not refresh.
this my code.

```
Locale localeIdn = new Locale("in");
Locale.setDefault(localeIdn);
Configuration config1 = new Configuration();
config1.locale = localeIdn;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config1, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(SettingPageActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Or this:

```
this.recreate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you.

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("yourlanguageid");
 LanguageHelper.changeLocale(mActivity.getResources(), locale);
 Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, mActivity.getClass());
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

---

```
public class LanguageHelper {
    /**
     * Change locale.
     *
     * @param res    the res
     * @param locale the locale
     */
    public static void changeLocale(Resources res, String locale) {

        Configuration config;
        config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());


        switch (locale) {
            case "yourlanguageid":
                config.locale = new Locale("yourlanguageid");
                break;
            case "en":
                config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                break;
        }
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public static Locale getLocale(Resources res) {
        Configuration config;
        config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        return config.locale;
    }
}
```